# jQuery Star-Based Voting Managing State

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery function that helps me with star-based ranking/voting. It works great and I got the example from a tutorial. When the user selects a star that numerical value is stored server-side and then if they come back to it that amount of stars are "yellow" and not "gray". It's only fault is that when you come back to it after voting and start hovering over the stars, your original stars that you selected do not remain "yellow" but get grayed out.

Here is my code and I apologize for its longevity:

```
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.starFunction = function (stars, initialRating) {
                //Save  the jQuery object for later use.
                var elements = this;

                //Go through each object in the selector and create a ratings control.
                return this.each(function () {

                    //Make sure intialRating is set.

                    if (!initialRating)
                        initialRating = 0;

                    //Save the current element for later use.
                    var containerElement = this;

                    //grab the jQuery object for the current container div
                    var container = jQuery(this);

                    //Create an array of stars so they can be referenced again.
                    var starsCollection = Array();

                    //Save the initial rating.
                    containerElement.rating = initialRating;

                    //Set the container div's overflow to auto.  This ensure it will                      grow to
                    //hold all of its children.
                    container.css('overflow', 'auto');

                    //create each star
                    for (var starIdx = 0; starIdx < stars; starIdx++) {

                        //Create a div to hold the star.
                        var starElement = document.createElement('div');

                        //Get a jQuery object for this star.
                        var star = jQuery(starElement);

                        //Store the rating that represents this star.
                        starElement.rating = starIdx + 1;

                        //Add the style.
                        star.addClass('jquery-ratings-star');

                        //Add the full css class if the star is beneath the initial rating.
                        if (starIdx < initialRating) {
                            star.addClass('jquery-ratings-full');
                        }

                        //add the star to the container
                        container.append(star);
                        starsCollection.push(star);

                        //hook up the click event
                        star.click(function () {
                            //When clicked, fire the 'ratingchanged' event handler.  Pass the rating through as the data argument.
                            elements.triggerHandler("ratingchanged", { rating: this.rating });
                            containerElement.rating = this.rating;
                        });

                        star.mouseenter(function () {
                            //Highlight selected stars.
                            for (var index = 0; index < this.rating; index++) {
                                starsCollection[index].addClass('jquery-ratings-full');
                            }
                            //Unhighlight unselected stars.
                            for (var index = this.rating; index < stars; index++) {
                                starsCollection[index].removeClass('jquery-ratings-full');
                            }
                        });

                        container.mouseleave(function () {
                            //Highlight selected stars.
                            for (var index = 0; index < containerElement.rating; index++) {
                                starsCollection[index].addClass('jquery-ratings-full');
                            }
                            //Unhighlight unselected stars.
                            for (var index = containerElement.rating; index < stars ; index++) {
                                starsCollection[index].removeClass('jquery-ratings-full');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using? If it is this one: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/ Then you should also supply us with the HTML you are using.

Comment: no it's not that one, though it looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use:

```
 star.unbind( 'mouseenter');
 star.unbind( 'mouseleave');
```

Within your click event or even:

```
$('.jquery-ratings-star').unbind( 'mouseenter');
$('.jquery-ratings-star').unbind( 'mouseleave');
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: that works fine so long as the user stays on the page. If they leave and come back and start hovering over the images they all gray out again. Seems like you're onto something.